# Is it possible to bleach a dark metal white? How so? With paint, or a chemical? oxidisation?

Tags: biology, fantasy-races

A character in my story, taking place in a Renaissance era time period, has metal bones as well as metal teeth.

How would he be able to make his teeth appear of the normal white color?

This is from a pre-established biological attribute I have given his race.

Comment: "Normal" to whom? And under what circumstances? Also "metal" is super non-specific which is not handy.

Comment: Welcome to World building Patrick. You have specified a time period, which is good, this helps people identify appropriate technologies, but we need to know what his teeth are made of in more detail. What metal exactly? Teeth made of Platinum will behave very differently to teeth made out of zinc.

Comment: Metal really can't be bleached.  It can be polished, painted, given an oxide coating or have one form naturally, as with aluminum or some steel alloys.

Comment: calcium is a metal, isn't it?

Comment: @RichardU in fact, it is a "reactive pale yellow metal that forms a dark oxide-nitride layer when exposed to air".

Comment: Why not a polished bronze layer? And if someone asks "I lost my teeth in an accident falling from a horse, this helps me talking and eating". Also, with the popularization of sugar at the end of the 15th century, people started getting caries, so black teeth wouldn't be so strange. Until then, most people just suffered severe tartar.

Comment: You want some white colored alloy to form the teeth or something durable and white that can conveniently be added to the surface of some particular metal?

Comment: Just **WHAT** metal are we talking about.

Comment: Instead of bleaching, why not use an alloy? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/White_metal

Comment: @Tim "white metal" isn't white.

Comment: While painting metal teeth isn't the same as oxidation it could do the trick. Simpler too. Alternatives would include an enamel or porcelain coating. Finding the right metal will be too hard. Paint or coat them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm pretty sure that with some metals their color is a result of their chemistry. I'd be worried that if you tried to 'bleach' his teeth white, it might compromise the structural integrity of the metal. Kinda like wearing down the enamel of our own teeth.

But, here's a fun idea. During the reign of Elizabeth the First, it became fashionable to dye the teeth black. This was because she had a penchant for sweets that rotted her teeth. Since sugar was relatively expensive, having black teeth became associated with being high class and wealthy.

If this is around your time frame, your character could paint his metal teeth black and just be a fashionably conscious Renaissance man.

Edit: I just realized I never answered *how* he would paint his teeth. My oversight, sorry. I think he would need to stuff Cotten in his cheeks, mouth, and under his tongue to get everything dry. Then he would need something like a [dental lip spreader](https://www.shutterstock.com/search?searchterm=Lip%20spreader&search_source=base_search_form&language=en&page=1&sort=popular&image_type=all&measurement=px&safe=true) to go in and paint, keeping some cotton under and around the tongue. Or he may swish it like mouthwash.

Comment: Okay, thanks for the responses. I did not think they would come back this quick. This is my first time here so I'm sorry if I'm not doing right, and I woils aprciate some constructive criticism on how to ask questions better. Now, the character. This is a fantasy world, but based on the renisance era/late medevil time period. The character I'm talking about has metal bones and teeth, a darkly colored fantasy metal, so if need be I can give it a tributes that would allow it to be collored. Is there any way to make his teeth apear white? I'm trying to avoid dentures

Comment: @Patrick Harvancik You probably could just paint them, but knowing the time period it won't be healthy. Here's an article that talks about paint and pigment in the renaissance (http://www.webexhibits.org/pigments/intro/renaissance.html). The problem with white paint in that era is that they tend to contain lead. Which isn't something you'd want in your mouth, but it may be accurate for him to use it and not know it's deadly.

Comment: It does also mention lime white, but I'm not sure how it holds up to a moist environment like the mouth

Comment: Oh, as for changes to the metal, just make his enamel somewhat similar to a primer and make his teeth maybe not be perfectly smooth. That'll give paint a place to grip onto.

Answer (score 0):

Better, and cooler, than some white metal would be false teeth.

[image: ivory false teeth]
http://phisick.com/core/wp-content/uploads/ivory-dentures-101-620x480.jpg

These could be bone, or antler, or wood, or ivory; whatever was done at the time.  They would not attract undue attention.

When the dentures are removed, the metal "tooth" underneath is a single serrated blade running along the ridge.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of bleaching his teeth and bones, he could have a few normal bone layers surrounding the outside of his metal bones and teeth. This would solve the bleaching problem and also eliminate some unsavoury side effects of metallic bones such as oxidation